# Why doesn't Entity Framework allow us to perform inserts, updates and deletes against the view?

Tags: entity-framework

Why doesn't Entity Framework allow us to perform inserts, updates or deletes against the view?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how EF works! It considers views as readonly.
But you can work around this limitation in a couple of ways.

- You can manually remove the `DefiningQuery` element from your view definition in the .edmx file (opened by xml editor). This works on simple views. But if you have even a bit complexity in your view (e.g. calculated column), you'll have problems doing this.
- Use stored procedures to do CRUD on your views. this is certainly more reliable.

For more detailed explanation, visit http://www.lucbos.net/2011/10/editable-views-in-entity-framework.html